# AWS RDS SQL Server Cross Database Query

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, rds

I am trying to compare SQL Azure vs AWS Sql server. SQL Azure clearly lists the limitation . I am trying to find the same on AWS SQL Server. My applicaiton currently uses cross database query. Which is not supported by  Azure. Is AWS RDS Sql server supports cross database query?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same question and decide just to have a go and see, the short answer is yes you can.

Basically you start up a SQL server instance in which you can create multiple databases and query across them as you would in any other standard SQL server instance

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can!!**

You can do cross database query in AWS SQL Server Instances. I'm doing cross database query with aws sql server instances for 2+ years now.

The following is the syntax

```
[Database_name].[Schema_name].[Table_name]
```

Example

```
Select u.[UserName], a.[Balance] From [db_detail].[dbo].[user_details] as u
INNER JOIN [db_account].[dbo].[acount_overview] AS a ON a.UserID = u.[UserID];
```